# Storing/Retrieving values in a Rails cookie and in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, controller, store

If I write cookies in this controller method:

```
class xxx1Controller < ApplicationController
  def xxx1
    cookies[:links] = []
    cookies[:links] << "xxx"
  end
end
```

So I want the cookies[:links] is an array now, but if I fetch value in another controller:

```
 class xxx2Controller < ApplicationController
      def xxx1
        @xx2 = cookies[:links] 
      end
 end
```

This give me an error, it says cookies[:links] in xxx2Controller is still a string!
How to fix this? I can't use an indirect variable, because it will die after restart server.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh it isn't answer which I want

Comment: @ShaoKahn sure it is, check the second to the marked as correct answer. Use `JSON.serialize`, arrays cannot be stored in cookies as is, that is not how cookie works.

Comment: **tl;dr** Rails doesn't handle it for you out of the box, hence cookies will always be strings. It's up to you how you want to serialize and deserialize your objects to and from said string.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank you

Comment: @mudasobwa but when I parse and do each, the value is a string not an object!

Comment: You should `JSON.generate` _before_ storing and `JSON.parse` _after_ loading.

Comment: @mudasobwa Now question is, I want push an object to an array when user click a link, and save this array to cookies, finally fetch this array from cookies in another controller. But I find JSON.generate just can add a complete array.

Comment: Store the array in the instance variable `@links` and do `cookies[:links] = JSON.generate(@links << "xxx")`.

Comment: Yeah, but I get some object_ids, how can I convert these object_id to real objects!

Comment: @mudasobwa I wanna `@links << @xxx` !, so I don't know how to fetch real objects

Comment: I do not follow anymore. Please open other question if you have other issue.